# How to create a timer counter in JSF

Tags: jsf, timer

I want to create an online test system, so i need a timer. When user start the test the timer will start counting down. But when user go to next question refresh the page the timer will still running. How can I do that any suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand the part "the timer will still running". Isn't that what you want? You need to elaborate the functional requirement in detail. Also mention what JSF version you're using.

Comment: because the code i found in google is javascript when you refresh the page the timer start over.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173598/jsf-please-help-how-to-display-timer/4177067#4177067

Comment: have you completed this application?

Answer (score 2):

You can use PrimeFaces [Poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml) option.

The counter will always be saved on the server.

Comment: Please provide an example. :) Link was dead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use PrimeFaces Extensions, they have [timer](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/timer/format.jsf) in their API.

Example: you put start of the test into `@SessionScoped` bean, then calculate seconds remaining which will be used as an input to `<pe:timer>` element:

```
@SessionScoped
public class UserData {
     private Date testStart; 

     /* getters and setters for testStart */

     public int secondsRemaining() {
        //calculate seconds remaining until end of the test from this.testStart
        return secondsRemaining;
     }
}
```

and then your test.xhtml would contain element

```
Time remaining: <pe:timer format="HH:mm:ss"
                    timeout="#{userData.secondsRemaining()}"/>
```