# Count down timer which don't reset on page refresh

Tags: jsf, timer

How can I create a count down timer in JSF? I don't want the timer reset when refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can simply use Java Script for it.](http://www.java-scripts.net/javascripts/Countdown-Timer.phtml)

Or

[You can use RichFaces a4j:poll and poll count data from server where your timer will be running](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/poll.jsf)

Comment: i know but i dont want when user refresh the page, the timer will reset.

Comment: @user236501 you can make ajax poll using DWR in simple JSP

Comment: Thanks for your advised, is there any simle way to do a count down timer in JSP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply this script

```
 var seconds = readCookie('countdown') || 60;
        alert(seconds);
        function secondPassed()
        {
            seconds--;
            var minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60);
            var remainingSeconds = parseInt(seconds % 60);
            if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
                remainingSeconds = "0" + parseInt(remainingSeconds);
            }
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + " mins : " + remainingSeconds + " secs";
           if (parseInt(seconds) === 0)
            {
                alert("Time is over");
                clearInterval(countdownTimer);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Time is Over";
                document.forms["myForm"].submit();
                document.location.href = "examresult.jsp";
            }
        }
        var countdownTimer = setInterval(function() {
            secondPassed();
            if (seconds === 0) {
                eraseCookie(seconds);
            } else {
                createCookie(seconds, seconds, 7);
            }
        }, 1000);
```