# Is it possible to make a p:dataTable with a column that contains a stopwatch using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm new with primefaces and JSF, but is there anyway to create a p:dataTable that has a
p:column which acts like a stopwatch?
Like this

```
Subject|Time Remaining|Subject Title
MATH   |   00:03:00   |Mathematics 1
SCIENCE|   00:33:00   |Science 1
HISTORY|   01:03:00   |History1
```

It gets the remaining time from a database, then the javascript code does the stopwatch so it is on client side. I already have a javascript code that does the ticking part for the remaining time, but It only works for one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Primefaces [Ajax Polling](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf) component which makes `ajax calls in a specified interval.`

Or else you can use put [Javascript](http://www.java-scripts.net/javascripts/Countdown-Timer.phtml) as specified in this [stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173598/count-down-timer-which-dont-reset-on-page-refresh/4177067#4177067).